# How to fix the M-920 Cain glitch in the mission Priority: Earth in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the mission Priority: Earth, after landing in London near the crash site, I push and get to the second floor of the destroyed building on which the wreckage is located but I can't find any M-920 Cain as the objective marker shows, the only thing lying around in there is a MedKit.

I tried reloading the game quite a few times, restarted the mission but to no good end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After suffering for a while I figured out a rather crude solution to the problem, editing the **Coalesced.bin** file to fix a hotkey to spawn the weapon.

It worked perfectly.

This is how you do it:

I’ve been stuck for quite some time for this bug, barring me from finishing Mass Effect 3. Then I remembered about the trick which I used to access all weapons, DLC and/or otherwise, by **editing** the **Coalesced.bin** file which actually is a compiled collection of multiple INI files.

What you’ll require is **[Wenchy’s Coalesced Editor](http://wenchy.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ME3Coalesced-latest.zip)**, which is way better than that of Gibbed (who is good for the savegame editor though …) and a functional brain with a sane mind.

If you seem to have the above stated at your disposal then please proceed to the next steps by first **backing up your original Coalesced.bin** file.

Open the **Coalesced Editor** and then proceed to opening the **Coalesced.bin** file which is located in **:\\BIOGame\CookedPCConsole**.

Then, from the left treelike menu, choose “**bioinput.ini**”, then “**sfxgame**”after that “**sfxgamemodedefault**”. The following screenshot would be helpful for you to identify the entries which are boxed in red for your convenience.

[image: Screenshot of the Coalesced.bin Editor]

In the right-hand side you’ll see the list from the **Bindings** section which shows how the key-bindings are defined for the game controls.

In the end of the list add the following line: **( Name=”F12″, Command=”giveitem self Cain” )**

**Save the changes in the Coalesced.bin file and start the game.**

Then **while in game, press F12 to access the M-920 Cain** to take down the Hades Cannon and move on to your next objective!

Comment: Please summarize the linked content here.  That way, if that site ever goes down, your answer is still valid.  Besides, it saves people a click!

Comment: If the link disappears, does this still answer the question?  Unless you can uneqivocally say yes to that, you *need to summarize the information*.

Comment: What you do is up to you.  I feel this doesn't hit our quality standards.

Comment: @Frank my apologies for being so rude and stupid. I hope this helps!
Had to run in a problem to realize how right you were. Cheers.